# Output of a function into a data.frame

Tags: r

I have two functions:

```
c <- function(i, n=2009, t=2000){
  vect1 <- vector('numeric', length(t:n))
  w <- n-t
  for(q in 0:w){
    a <- 1/((1+i)^(q+1))
    b <- q+t
    vect1[q+1] <- a
  }
  return(vect1)
}
```

and

```
p <- function(i, n=2009, t=2000){
  w <- n-t
  for(q in 0:w){
    a <- c(i, n, q+t)
    print(a)
  } 
}
```

Upon defining both functions and running p(0.10), a table similar to the following is obtained, but it is printed.  I need the output in a data.frame so that I can join it with other data.

```
0.909090909 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0.826446281 0.909090909 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0.751314801 0.826446281 0.909090909 0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0.683013455 0.751314801 0.826446281 0.909090909 0   0   0   0   0   0
0.620921323 0.683013455 0.751314801 0.826446281 0.909090909 0   0   0   0   0
0.56447393  0.620921323 0.683013455 0.751314801 0.826446281 0.909090909 0   0   
etc.
```

Comment: Replace `print` function with `rbind` or `cbind` - check in documentation what this functions do and pick the one you need :)

Comment: I've tried this and the resulting data.frame only has one vector, namely the first which is generated. If I use something like rbind(print(a)), I get a similar table, but is cannot be manipulated.

Comment: *really* not a good idea to call a function '`c()`'.

Comment: In function `p`, immediately before the loop include `d <- data.frame()`, immediately after the `print` include `d <- rbind.data.frame(d, a)` and as the last line of the function (outside the loop) include just `d`. And like @RobertMc says, call `c` somethign else. But not `t`, the name of the matrix transpose function. And `q` is the `quit` the R session function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* do something like this, which gives you a one-column data frame. I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do, or to what other data you want to join this. Maybe it will help you get to where you're trying to go:

```
cFunc <- function(i, n=2009, t=2000){
  vect1 <- vector('numeric', length(t:n))
  w <- n-t
  for(q in 0:w){
    a <- 1/((1+i)^(q+1))
    b <- q+t
    vect1[q+1] <- a
  }
  return(vect1)
}

p <- function(i, n=2009, t=2000){
  w <- n-t
  a1 <- list()
  for(q in 0:w){
    q <- q+1
    a1[[q]] <- cFunc(i, n, q+t)
  } 
  return(a1)
}
listp <- p(0.10)
listp <- lapply(listp, as.data.frame)
listp <- data.table::rbindlist(listp, fill = TRUE)
```

Result:

```
> head(listp)
      X[[i]]
1: 0.9090909
2: 0.8264463
3: 0.7513148
4: 0.6830135
5: 0.6209213
6: 0.5644739
```